# How can I select my visualforce page to custom button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-button

When I choose my `Visualforce Page` appended to a `Custom Button`, I find that I cannot choose pages which use a custom controller at all, and sometimes just some of the pages which use the standard controller.

Comment: based on same SObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **`Detail Button`**, you must implement `StandardController`, and for a **`List Button`**, you must implement `StandardSetController`.

**Detail Button**

```
<apex:page StandardController="MyObject__c">
```

**List Button**

```
<apex:page StandardController="MyObject__c" recordSetVar="records">
```

If you want to include any extensions, they must define a constructor that accepts the relevant controller.

**Detail Button**

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

**List Button**

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
{
    // constructor logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how Visualforce actions, buttons and links are designed to work. Pages that use standardController (and optionally recordSetVar) are intended to be used against a specific record or set of records from a given object type. You'll find tons of examples and explanations in the documentation, including [Mass-Updating Records with a Custom List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_massupdate.htm), [Overriding Tabs Using a Standard List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_overrides.htm), [Adding Custom List Buttons using Standard List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_custom_button.htm), and other places as well. They allow you to define new actions for an object's home page, a button or link on a detail page, or a button on a related list or list view that contains that specific object type.